# setting TransparencyKey on windows form and making it child of an office application using setparent hides the form

Tags: wpf, winforms, excel, excel-2010

I want to show a WinForm inside excel application. But this window should be transparent.
For that I do the following.

```
  private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // other form/ control init code
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        // other form/ control init code
    }
```

Now I want to make this form as child of the excel application for that matter I use the following code.

```
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)     
 {
   // PINVOKE CALL
   User32.SetParent(FORMHANDLE, EXCELAPPHANDLE);   
 }
```

After setting this the form disappears, because if I uncomment the above code I can see the form with trasparent background.

Comment: Only a top-level window supports the Opacity and TransparencyKey properties.  Use the form's Show(owner) overload instead.

Comment: thanks @HansPassant , I tried with the below code             frm.Show(IWIN32ExcelAppWindow); but then the from acts as MDI form and it doesnt allow to click on the parent excel application.